# Subscription in Angular app not retrieving data

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is the code exceuted when I navigate to the `Conversation-List` page of my Angular app:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.authSub = this.authService.userId.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(userId => {
        console.log('NG ONINIT');
        this.conversationsSub = this.conversationsService.conversations.subscribe(conversations => {
          loadingEl.dismiss();
          this.loadedConversations = conversations.filter(
            conversation =>
              conversation.userId === userId || conversation.mechanicId === userId
          );
          console.log('Loaded Conversations:', this.loadedConversations);
        })
      });
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('ION VIEW WILL ENTER');
    this.conversationsService.fetchConversations().subscribe();
  }
```

When I initially navigate to this page, the `User` details are displayed in the console:

[image: initialLoad]

[image]

However, when I refresh the page, the `User` is empty:

[image: whenIRefreshPage]

[image]

Can someone please tell me why the User is undefined when I refresh the page?

This `User` object is used to in the `Conversation-list` below:

`Conversation-list.page.html`:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let conversation of loadedConversations">
    <app-conversation-item [conversation]="conversation"></app-conversation-item>
</ion-item>
```

Typescript:

```
export class ConversationItemComponent {

    @Input() conversation: Conversation;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.usersSub = this.usersService.getUserByUserId(this.conversation.mechanicId).subscribe(  
            user => {
                console.log(`User`, user);
                console.log(`Username`, user.name);
                console.log(`Image URL`, user.imageUrl);
                this.username = user.name;
                this.imageUrl = user.imageUrl;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: try to copy-paste the username variable from the object itself to guarantee the letter case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 points you can improve:

1 - Don't use nested subscriptions, as this is not considered a best practice with RxJS. You can use for example `combineLatest`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest([this.authService.userId, this.conversationsService.fetchConversations()])
   .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
   .subscribe(([userId, loadedConversations]) => {
      console.log('UserId', userId);
      this.loadedConversations = loadedConversations.filter(
        conversation =>
          conversation.userId === userId || conversation.mechanicId === userId
        );
      console.log('Loaded Conversations', this.loadedConversations);
     }
  }

// ionViewWillEnter() has been removed, as we embed the call in combineLatest
```

`combineLatest` operator expects that both observables emit a value. Otherwise you can use the `withLatestFrom()` operator if you are interested in fetching only the latest value of one of the 2 observables (eg. Auth Service).

2 - In case the code is in a component, you should remember to unsubscribe from obervables in order to avoid introducing memory leaks. You can use for example `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` operator and a subject that you call in the onDestroy component hook:

```
private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one question about combining the subscriptions, would this  be called in `ngOnInit()` or `ionViewWilEnter()`?

Comment: You can keep it in your `ngOnInit()` method, this is usually the place where we fetch data from the service in components. Actually you do not need the ionViewWillEnter. I edit my answer with this aspect.

Comment: OK, there seems to be a closing tag or something like that missing from the `ngOnInit()` method. I'll try to find out what is missing exactly

Comment: Also, if I remove `ionViewWillEnter()`, no conversations are displayed

Comment: From where did you call the ionViewWillEnter()? If you call `this.conversationsService.fetchConversations()` this should fetch your data (but I am just guessing as these code portions are missing). Can you create a stackblitz with you code? This would make it easier to debug it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/damosull/mychanic Issue is with `Conversation-List`

Comment: The stackblitz keeps compiling endlessly without showing the project. Can you just use a portion of the project instead of all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212794/discussion-between-user9847788-and-francesco).